# Unneccesary postgres array casting required?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, casting, any

Having following setup in Postgres 9.3:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INTEGER);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

I'm aggregating these values into array (don't ask why, the actual setup is very complex, so I simply need this approach).

Now I need to check whether some integer belongs to the array. Tried this:

```
SELECT 1=ANY((SELECT array_agg(id) FROM t))
```

Got error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
LINE 1: SELECT 1=ANY((SELECT array_agg(id) FROM t))
                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

After some experimentation found a working solution:

```
SELECT 1=ANY((SELECT array_agg(id) FROM t)::integer[])
```

Why does postgres require me to cast integer[] to integer[]? Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the inner select (`SELECT array_agg(id) FROM t`) is not a `integer[]` it is a resultset containing a single row containing an `integer[]`.

You can expose what's going on in two ways.

If you try

`SELECT 1=ANY((SELECT array_agg(id) FROM t)::text[]);`

the error message is 
`ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text`

Note that the error message does not refer to a `text[]` but to a `text`.

This is because the equality is comparing the left argument to each element of the right argument.  Hence, in your original query, it is a resultset of `integer[]`, and it is trying to compare the `1` to each (you only have one) `integer[]`.

Another way to see this is to reflect on

`select count(*) from (select array_agg(id) from t) as z`

This embeds your original subquery as `z` -- and it returns 1 row.  If you try to cast `z` to an `integer[]` it won't work -- because the FROM clause needs a resultset, not an integer array.

However, one can cast a resultset containing one row with one column, to an instance of the type of that singleton (in this case, an `integer[]`).   This disambiguates between "I'm looking in any of the rows of this subquery" to "I'm looking in the array of the single row/column of this subquery".

Hence, the requirement to explicitly cast.